# How to alter the dimensions of a Facetgrid scatterplot to prevent overlapping axis labels?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to increase the size of x and y axis to eliminate overlapping of ticks. Also can we rotate this Component labeling horizontally.

Following is the code:
[image: THIS IS THE CURRENT OUTPUT]

```
fg = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, hue='Component',aspect=1.61)
_=plt.grid(which='major', color='#cccccc', alpha=0.45)
_=plt.title('testing', family="Arial", fontsize=12)
_=plt.xlabel("x")
_=plt.ylabel("y")

plt.yticks(AV_df.index,AV_df.Affects_version.values)

scale_factor = 0.1
scale_factorx = 5
ymin, ymax = plt.ylim()
fig= plt.figure(figsize=(3,10))

plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
plt.ylim(ymin * scale_factor, ymax * scale_factor)

fg.map(plt.scatter,'ts','Affects_version').add_legend()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Plotting a scatter plot with Facetgrid

- The reason to use a scatterplot with Facetgrid is to enable the use of the `hue` parameter, which isn't available with `scatter`
- This data has 10000 rows, 26 unique values for the y-axis and 26 unique components.
- Properly setting the `height` and `aspect` parameters is the key to controlling the figure size.

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
import string

# create synthetic data
np.random.seed(365)
random.seed(365)
data = {'affects': [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(10000)],
        'ts': [np.random.randint(10, 80) for _ in range(10000)],
        'component': [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(10000)]}

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# plot
fg = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, hue='component', height=16, aspect=0.8)
fg.map(plt.scatter, 'ts', 'affects').add_legend()
```

[image]